# ReportViewer disappears after clicking link inside ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services, report, reportviewer

I have a ReportViewer (for SSRS) in an ASP.NET application.

The user enters in parameter information through the web form and then submits it.

The ReportViewer then returns a small report that shows counts of the information requested.

Next to these counts are links (assigned in BIDS) to link to the corresponding report using the parameters already entered.

It all renders fine until I click one of the links in the ReportViewer. It will then give the brief "Loading" dialog and then the ReportViewer disappears.

Not sure how to handle this and I can't find much information on it. I would ideally like the selected report to open in a new window (no URL bar, etc).

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with how ReportViewer was installed on our development and production servers. So when it seems like nothing else can explain what is going on with the ReportViewer... make sure the DLLs are properly installed on your server.